# faster n choose k for combination of array ruby

Tags: ruby, combinatorics

While trying to solve the "paths on a grid" problem, I have written the code

```
def paths(n, k)
  p = (1..n+k).to_a
  p.combination(n).to_a.size
end
```

The code works fine, for instance `if n == 8 and k == 2` the code returns `45` which is the correct number of paths.

However the code is very slow when using larger numbers and I'm struggling to figure out how to quicken the process.

Comment: Use `p.combination(n).size` instead.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the suggestion. While this works and I assume it has sped up the process, to the naked eye it is still taking a similar amount of time to figure out the larger numbers. To be clear you were referring to the needless .to_a rather than the code on the line above?

Comment: @Stefan apologies, it is much quicker. Thanks

Comment: @Oscady yes, because `#to_a` in Ruby returns a whole new object with the elements found in the Enumerator. This requires more time and memory. Check [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a) for info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than building the array of combinations just to count it, just write the [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) that defines the number of combinations. I'm sure there are also gems that include this and many other combinatorics functions.

Note that I am using the gem [Distribution](https://github.com/clbustos/distribution) for the `Math.factorial` method, but that is another easy one to write. Given that, though, I'd suggest taking @stefan's answer, as it's less overhead.

```
def n_choose_k(n, k)
  Math.factorial(n) / (Math.factorial(k) * Math.factorial(n - k))
end

n_choose_k(10, 8)
# => 45
```

Note that the `n` and `k` here refer to slightly different things than in your method, but I am keeping them as it is highly standard nomenclature in combinatorics for this function.

Comment: It is just one of basic combinatorics issues, not a Ruby. Smart answer.

Comment: Where does `Math.factorial` come from?

Comment: Good catch @stefan, I had forgotten it was not standard Ruby. I am using the [Distribution](https://github.com/clbustos/distribution) gem, which extends `Math`. Probably simpler then (and, at least on my machine, even faster for some reason) to do it your way.

Comment: 8 choose 6 is 28, not 45.  `8 * 7 / 2`.

Comment: @pjs sorry, the test I ran was 8 choose 2. My mistake

Comment: @Oscady `(8 choose 2) == (8 choose 6)` because of the way the cancellations work.

Comment: @pjs right you are. I entered the values of n and k instead of 10 choose 2 which is 45.

Comment: Depending on `n` and `k`, `(n-k+1..n).reduce(:*)/Math.factorial(k)` may be faster (don't know).

Answer (score 6):

The answers that suggest computing full factorials will generate lots of unnecessary overhead when working with big numbers. You should use the method below for calculating the binomial coefficient: n!/(k!(n-k)!)

```
def n_choose_k(n, k)
  return 0 if k > n
  result = 1
  1.upto(k) do |d|
    result *= n
    result /= d
    n -= 1
  end
  result
end
```

This will perform the minimum operations needed. Note that incrementing d while decrementing n guarantees that there will be no rounding errors. For example, {n, n+1} is guaranteed to have at least one element divisible by two, {n, n+1, n+2} is guaranteed to have at least one element divisible by three and so on.

Your code can be rewritten as:

```
def paths(x, y)
  # Choice of x or y for the second parameter is arbitrary
  n_choose_k(x + y, x)
end

puts paths(8, 2) # 45
puts paths(2, 8) # 45
```

I assume that n and k in the original version were meant to be dimensions so i labeled them x and y instead. There's no need to generate an array here.

Edit: Here is a benchmark script...

```
require 'distribution'

def puts_time
  $stderr.puts 'Completed in %f seconds' % (Time.now - $start_time)
  $start_time = Time.now
end

def n_choose_k(n, k)
  return 0 if k > n
  result = 1
  1.upto(k) do |d|
    result *= n
    result /= d
    n -= 1
  end
  result
end

def n_choose_k_distribution(n, k)
  Math.factorial(n) / (Math.factorial(k) * Math.factorial(n - k))
end

def n_choose_k_inject(n, k)
  (1..n).inject(:*) / ((1..k).inject(:*) * (1..n-k).inject(:*))
end

def benchmark(&callback)
  100.upto(300) do |n|
    25.upto(75) do |k|
      callback.call(n, k)
    end
  end
end

$start_time = Time.now

puts 'Distribution gem...'
benchmark { |n, k| n_choose_k_distribution(n, k) }
puts_time

puts 'Inject method...'
benchmark { |n, k| n_choose_k_inject(n, k) }
puts_time

puts 'Answer...'
benchmark { |n, k| n_choose_k(n, k) }
puts_time
```

Output on my system is:

```
Distribution gem...
Completed in 1.141804 seconds
Inject method...
Completed in 1.106018 seconds
Answer...
Completed in 0.150989 seconds
```

Comment: better if you can benchmark this to support your answer.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon, thanks for the recommendation. I figured it was obvious that there were fewer operations performed but we don't know unless we test, right?

Comment: yes it is very fast certainly compared with the solutions using factorials and in combination with big numbers but with these big numbers the result is't correct (0..599266).to_a.combination(2).size != n_choose_k(5992666, 2), can't compare the result with the other solutions though since the calculation takes forever

Comment: found the problem, at least if the k is 2, you leave out the line result /= d and at the end return result/2

Comment: Note that `(0..599266).to_a.combination(2).size == n_choose_k(5992666, 2)` evaluates to `false` but `(0..599266).to_a.combination(2).size == n_choose_k((0..599266).to_a.size, 2)` evaluates to `true`. That's because the size of the array created from `(0..599266).to_a` is actually 599267, not 599266. The function is returning the correct results.

Answer (score 4):

```
def combinations(n, k)
  return 1 if k == 0 or k == n
  (k + 1 .. n).reduce(:*) / (1 .. n - k).reduce(:*)
end

combinations(8, 2)  #=> 28
```

### Explanation about the math part

The original equation is

```
combinations(n, k) = n! / k!(n - k)!
```

Since `n! / k! = (1 * 2 * ... * n) / (1 * 2 * ... * k)`, for any `k <= n` there is a `(1 * 2 * ... * k)` factor both in the numerator and in the denominator, so we can cancel this factor. This makes the equation become

```
combinations(n, k) = (k + 1) * (k + 2) * ... * (n) / (n - k)!
```

which is exactly what I did in my Ruby code.

Comment: Nice use of `reduce`

Comment: I have seen others do similar to this while searching but I couldn't quite figure it out. I will have to look into this a bit more. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Oscady I added the math explanation. If what you can't figure out is `reduce`, please refer to the [ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)

Comment: @Aetherus that is class,  thanks for the help with this. There's a lot of things I could've done much nicer with this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're interested in the count rather than the actual combination sets, you should do this with a `choose` function. The mathematical definition involves evaluating three different factorials, but there's a lot of cancellation going on so you can speed it up by using ranges to avoid the calculations that will be cancelled anyway.

```
class Integer
  def choose(k)
    fail 'k > n' if k > self
    fail 'args must be positive' if k < 0 or self < 1
    return 1 if k == n || k == 0
    mm = [self - k, k].minmax
    (mm[1]+1..self).reduce(:*) / (2..mm[0]).reduce(:*)
  end
end

p 8.choose 6  # => 28
```

To solve your paths problem, you could then define

```
def paths(n, k)
  (n + k).choose(k)
end

p paths(8, 2)  # => 45
```

Answer (score 0):

The reduce/inject versions are nice. But since speed seemed to be a bit of an issue, I'd suggest the n_choose_k versions from @google-fail.
It is quite insightful and suggests a ~10-fold speed increase.

I would suggest that the iteration use the Lesser of k and ( n - k ).
N-choose-K and N-choose-(N-K) produce the same result (the factors in the denominator are simply reversed). So something like a 52-choose-51 could be done in one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do the following:

```
class Integer
  def !
    (2..self).reduce(1, :*)
  end

  def choose(k)
    self.! / (k.! * (self-k).!)
  end
end
```

Benchmarking:

```
k = 5

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000].each do |n|
    x.report("#{n}") { n.choose(k) }
  end
end
```

On my machine I get:

```
       user     system      total        real
10  0.000008   0.000001   0.000009 (  0.000006)
100  0.000027   0.000003   0.000030 (  0.000031)
1000  0.000798   0.000094   0.000892 (  0.000893)
10000  0.045911   0.013201   0.059112 (  0.059260)
100000  4.885310   0.229735   5.115045 (  5.119902)
```

Not the fastest thing on the planet, but it's okay for my uses. If it ever becomes a problem, then I can think about optimizing